# Can I use nohup on a shell script rather than a specific command?

Tags: shell, nohup

If I have a shell script named `shell.sh` can I enter this at the command line:

```
$ nohup shell.sh
```

and the script will run to completion even if I log out?  Or do I need to `nohup` every line in the script?

Comment: Use: `nohup shell.sh&`

Comment: A shell script **is** a "specific command" in the eyes of the OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Do whatever you do to normally run the script, just put `nohup` in front of it.

If you normally run `shell.sh`, then yes, you can run `nohup shell.sh`.

If you instead do `./shell.sh` you should `nohup ./shell.sh`.